# Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\XXXXExcel.xlsx'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I try to open the Excel file by this code.But i got an error like this

> Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\XXXXExcel.xlsx'. There are
>   several possible reasons:
>
> • The file name or path does not exist.
>  • The file is being used by
>   another program.
>  • The workbook you are trying to save has the same
>   name as a currently open workbook.

Plz help me..

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = app.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

Comment: In what context is this code running? Within a web part, a feature, a timer job? Where is the excel file you are trying to open? Please provide more detail.

Comment: How is this related to SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

Varna,

have a look at the OpenXML SDK. See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850837.aspx) for examples of what you can do

Great video that explains using of Open XML sdk and also has example of using it with SharePoint

Source: [Interacting with Excel spreadsheet from Sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7227/interacting-with-excel-spreadsheet-from-sharepoint-2010)

However, your answer accept rate is quite low! Please accept it if it resolves your issue!